# Unable To Change File Name on my external Hardrive pluged in my Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, macos

[image]I can't seem to see any options to rename a folder on my external Hard Drive. Please help! :( I have already checked and its not locked and I have the read and write privileged.

P.S
I'm on MacOS Catalina Version 10.15.3

[image]

Comment: This is likely a permissions issue.  Select the folder in question and press `Cmd-I` or right click and select “Get Info”. Post a screen capture to your question

Comment: And you've tried the normal way by clicking on the name??

Comment: @Allan I edited my post and added a screenshot of the get info.

Comment: @jmh yes I did.. and nothing's happening

Comment: If you look under "Sharing & Permissions" it says *You can only read* confirming the permission issue.  I've written an answer on how to take ownership of a file/folder.  Please give that a try:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/382683/119271